# django-registration email domain whitelist

Tags: python, django

I am trying to set up an email domain whitelist for my project's registration form.

I am using [django-registration](https://github.com/ubernostrum/django-registration).

Here is my 'register' url rule

```
urlpatterns = [
    ...
    url(r'^register/$',
        RegistrationView.as_view(),
        { 'form_class': EmailDomainFilterRegistrationForm },
        name='registration_register'),
    ...
]
```

And here is the `EmailDomainFilterRegistrationForm` class I created

```
from django.core.validators import EmailValidator

from registration.forms import RegistrationForm

class EmailDomainFilterRegistrationForm(RegistrationForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(EmailDomainFilterRegistrationForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['email'].validators = [
            EmailValidator(whitelist=['epita.fr', 'lrde.epita.fr']),
        ]
```

The problem is that the whitelist is not applied at all. I can register with any email I want.

**What am I doing wrong?**

> Django version 1.9.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how to do it (the right way).

Create a subclass of `registration.forms.RegistrationForm`:

```
class EmailDomainFilterRegistrationForm(RegistrationForm):

    def clean_email(self):
        submitted_data = self.cleaned_data['email']

        if not ALLOWED_DOMAINS: # If we allow any domain
            return submitted_data

        domain = submitted_data.split('@')[1]
        logger.debug(domain)
        if domain not in ALLOWED_DOMAINS:
            raise forms.ValidationError(
                u'You must register using an email address with a valid '
                'domain ({}). You can change your email address later on.'
                .format(', '.join(self.allowed_domains))
            )
        return submitted_data
```

Re-use *django-registration*'s `urls.py` from whichever *django-registration* backend you're using and change the `registration_register` url with

```
url(r'^register/$',
    RegistrationView.as_view(form_class=EmailDomainFilterRegistrationForm),
    name='registration_register'),
```

`RegistrationView` above depends on which of *django-registration*'s backends you're using. Don't import it from the top level `views.py`. Import it from the applicable backend using **ONE** of the following statements:

```
from registration.backends.hmac.views import RegistrationView
from registration.backends.model_activation.views import RegistrationView
from registration.backends.simple.views import RegistrationView
```